# prettyPhoto Open inline content onLoad

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I got an inline with `id="inline"` content with simple text on an image.

Is there a possibility to open this inline on page load?

Any help, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.prettyPhoto.open("#inline");
});
```

Comment: how to pass width and height when using above function ?

Comment: You can pass default width and heights while binding As follow: $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'facebook',slideshow:false,callback: function(){$('.more-brand').show();},default_width: 980});  //Of course, its default and will affects all pretty boxes on same page, You can bind separately if you want different.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function(){
        $.prettyPhoto.open('your-file-name.html?iframe=true&width=auto&height=80%; rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]"' );
    });